# Navbar Disappears when setting BrowserRouter Route Tag

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning React and trying to understand why in this instance is the Navbar disappears whenever I try and use the Route tag.

**This is my App.js:**

I have imported as below

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

When I add the below without the route component my nave displays, but when I add them then the navbar disappears and there view is blank

```
return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
     
      {/* <Route>
        //Home
      </Route>
      
      <Route>
        //Home1
      </Route>
     
      <Route>
        //Home2
      </Route> */}

    </Router>
```

[image]

**This is my Navbar.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Navbar() {
    return <nav className="navbar bg-dark container">
        <h3><Link to="/">Home</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to="/Home1">Home1</Link></h3>
        <h3><Link to="/Home2">Home2</Link></h3>
    </nav>
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using ?

Comment: @CyrusZei it looks like "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",